# How to send object in ejs as function parameter

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean, ejs

how to send object as paremeter in ejs . when i try to send object in parameter for test function it prints undefined .

```
</tr>
    <% userlist.forEach(function(usr){ %>
    <tr>
        <td><input readonly type="text" value="<%= usr.name %>"></td> 
        <td><input readonly type="text" value="<%= usr.email %>"></td>
        <td style="cursor:pointer">
        <i title="edit data" style="padding-right:18px" class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
        <i title="delete" ng-click='test(<%= usr %>)' class="fa fa-trash"></i></td>      
    </tr>
    <% }) %>  
    <% } %>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking, send to who and what object?

Comment: send a object to angular test function as parameter .  here : ng-click='test(<%= usr %>)'

Comment: It looks like what you are doing should work fine. Do the user's name and email address show up in the table? Could you show your AngularJS `test` function as well?

Comment: alert comes with undefined :                    app.controller('cntr',function($scope , $http){
      $scope.test=function(obj){ alert(obj);}
    });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like `ejs` stringifies whatever is inside the `<%= %>` tag. When I tried your code, I got this error:

```
Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 16 of the expression [test([object] starting at [{4}].
```

So I can't reproduce your "undefined" behaviour.

However, it looks like there is a way for it to work:

```
<button ng-click="test(<%= JSON.stringify(usr) %>)">
```

The `test` function actually receives an object here, not a string.

Alternatively, you could only pass the id of the user to the delete function, like this:

```
ng-click="test(<%= usr.id %>)"
```

Answer (score -1):

You can send any data via rendering templates.

```
   res.render("myPage",{title:"String",age:Number,userlist:[{},{},{}]}})
```

Comment: This does not answer the question.